# Linter error - Browser-only function is not defined

Tags: node.js, webpack, filereader

I'm relying on a class that is available in browser, `FileReader`

I keep getting an error in webpack - `'FileReader' is not defined                  no-undef`

What is the correct way of dealing with this? I'm currently using a method where I just ignore the message.

Comment: This is the line that's causing the error `var reader = new FileReader()`

Comment: The code is meant to run in browser and should use browser's `FileReader` class

Comment: I'm using it in an action inside a packaged framework. Because Node is looking for `FileReader` when it is compiling and linting and it doesn't exist, it causes an error when compiling. I was looking for a way for it to ignore this exception as a workaround, until I found out that I could target it using `window.FileReader`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is that since webpack cannot find it as part of Node.js and since it is not available, it will cause an error. But there are a few ways of getting around this.

Instead of

```js
var reader = new FileReader();
```

use

### Fix #1

```js
var reader = new window.FileReader();
```

### Fix #2

```js
var reader = new global.FileReader();
```

webpack, by default, will convert global to window.
More info at: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/

### Fix #3

```js
// in webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
    FileReader: 'FileReader'
  }
};
```

more info: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/