# How to read an image file (pixel data) into a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing

I have a very basic question: how can I read an image file in javascript and get access to its pixel data as arrays?  I am writing a local script to be run as `node myscript.js`, so no need for any web-stuff.

Basically I need a javascript equivalent of the following python 2-liner, preferably with as few external dependencies as possible:

```
import skimage.io
image = skimage.io.imread('someimage.file',as_gray=False).astype('float64')
# do stuff to image
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read a file/image using a `FileReader()` object in javascript.

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader):

> The `FileReader` object lets web applications asynchronously read the contents of files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer, using File or Blob objects to specify the file or data to read.

And after reading an image, you can use a third-party library to manipulate it. Here are a few good libraries:

- [Caman JS](http://camanjs.com/)
- [glfx.js](http://evanw.github.io/glfx.js/)
- [Grafi.js](https://github.com/grafijs/grafi)
- [Jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp)

**A basic example of reading file**:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('image.jpg', function(err, data){
   console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Saud.  I think I tried doing this, and I cannot even seem to construct a FileReader() object:
```var reader = new FileReader();```
results in:
             ^

ReferenceError: FileReader is not defined

I would really appreciate a really basic example of how to read an image file, say 'example.png' from the current script's directory into arrays.

Comment: @rafexiap I've edited my answer and included a basic example. You've mentioned that you're getting a *Reference Error* that's because `FileReader` is a browser class. You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871095/linter-error-browser-only-function-is-not-defined) for this matter.

Comment: One more thing, if you use the above mentioned libraries you won't need a `FileReader` object. Those can directly modify an image